# On Laravel I'm trying to update an image and It works, but when I decide not to add a new file I get this error: General error: 1364

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to update a table and it works perfectly but when I try to update whiteout changing the file it fails and gives me this error.

The error:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'poster' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `patrocinadores` (`nombre`, `link`, `categoria`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Patrocinadores, http://127.0.0.1:8000/patrocinadores/creates, 3, 2017-05-01 23:44:44, 2017-05-01 23:44:44))

Here is my controller store()

```
public function store(Request $request){

    $this->validate(request(), [

        'nombre' => 'required',
        'link' => 'required',
        'poster' => 'image|image_size:<=1000',
        'categoria' =>'required',
    ]);

    $patrocinadores = new Patrocinadores;

    $patrocinadores->nombre = request('nombre');
    $patrocinadores->link = request('link');
    $newFoto=request()->file('poster');
    if($newFoto){
      $name=$newFoto. '.' . $newFoto->getClientOriginalExtension();
      $patrocinadores->poster = $newFoto->move('./uploads/', $name);
    }
    $patrocinadores->categoria = request('categoria');

    $patrocinadores->save();


    return redirect('/patrocinadores'); }
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="form-control-file">
    <label for="poster">Póster</label>

      <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="poster" name="poster" aria-describedby="fileHelp"  accept="image/*" >

      <br>
      <div id="preview"><img src="{{asset($patrocinadores->poster)}}" ></div>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place you set the poster field is in the if statement... so if $request->file() returns null it will never get set... probably what happens...

```
  $newFoto=request()->file('poster');
    if($newFoto){
      $name=$newFoto. '.' . $newFoto->getClientOriginalExtension();
      $patrocinadores->poster = $newFoto->move('./uploads/', $name);
    }
```

Now $newFoto is an instance of Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile, the move() method on it returns a file object...

You could take advantage of the storeAs() method and store the path of the file in the database... like so:

```
$patrocinadores->poster = $request->poster->storeAs('uploads', $name);
```

Note that this will store it in your storage directory under uploads (/storage/uploads) which I prefer over root... now even better... you can check for file upload success, the user could abort on you...

```
    if ($request->file('poster')->isValid()) {
        $patrocinadores->poster = $request->poster->storeAs('uploads', $name);
    }
    else{
        $patrocinadores->poster = 'path to default photo or avatar';
    }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Very nice answer, thank you very much :)